How to emphasis on value $c$ in the definition of unit step function
Let $c\geq 0$. The unit step function $U(x-c)$ is defined by
$$
U(x-c)=
\begin{cases}0,\quad 0\leq x < c, \\
1,\quad x\geq c.
\end{cases}
$$
As I didn't find which one of the followings can be used, so make me light which one is better to say?

"The unit step function $U(x-c)$ at $c$ is defined to be..."

"The unit step function $U(x-c)$ in a neighborhood of $c$ is defined to be..."

????


If you know a word which I can use to emphasis on c, please note me. This is routinely done when studying continuity of a function or study the Taylor expansion. Thanks!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Community I am assking how to say the function is defined according to selectedc? Is it ok to say at c or about c or in a neighborhood c or ?????

Writing $U_c(x) = U(x-c)$ would be much better. Then, $c$ is part of the name of the function itself. And I would say that none of your proposals clarify what $U_c$ is. The definition itself is clear enough.

@mathcounterexamples.net :  Oh... yes. Why haven't I thought that.....

@mathcounterexamples.net thanks. thanks.

$U(0)=0$ according to your definition, which is the value of your function when $x=c$

@Paul In fact $U_c(c) = 1$.

Lol, so it is. Easier to read by defining $U_c (x)$ and put all the c info into the domain.
